# Get typing value from Strut2 jquery Autocompleter

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, struts2

I want to create an auto-completing combo box from the `Autocompleter` option in struts2-jquery-plugin. Are there any way to get the typing string to POJO variable. so far I have seen loading SQL list to JSON and then giving suggestions. I want to get the string when a person is typing and runt the SQL query and return the JSON object.so far I have done the JSON part, the problem is with getting the typing string from < sj:autocompleter >, there is a way to get this by ajax, can anyone help me, here is my codes

```
  <s:url var="remoteurl" action="autoCompleterAction"/>
<sj:autocompleter
        id="user"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        delay="50"
        loadMinimumCount="2"

/>
```

Struts.xml

```
   <action name="autoCompleterAction" class="com.doerit.action.AjaxAutoComplete" method="setCombo">
    <result name="success" type="json">
    <param name="root">newnames</param>

        </result>
    </action>`
```

**EDIT 1:**
okay now i wrote a ajax to get JSON object to my java class.above task i mentioned is complete, now Autocompleter is not firing the struts event to get JSON data.so how to fire the struts event

this is my scrpit so far;

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="autoCompleterAction"/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//    document.getElementById ("user_widget").addEventListener ("keyup", getname, false);

    function getname() {
        var text1=document.getElementById("user_widget").value.trim();
        console.log(text1);
        $.ajax({
            url: "userinput.html",
            type: "Post",
            data:JSON.stringify({"name":text1}),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function (resp) {

                console.log(resp);

            },

        })
    }
</script>

<sj:autocompleter
        id="user"
        name="user"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        delay="50"
        loadMinimumCount="2"
        onkeyup="getname()"

/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed the plugin and used jquery autocomplete with full ajax JSON responses. now its working. if anyone interested you can find the code from here [Jquery Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887387/how-to-get-selected-value-from-autocomplete-box-using-ajax)